# Updating Kendo grid row on column value change

Tags: asp.net-mvc-4, kendo-ui

I am working on an MVC .Net Framework v4.5 site using Kendo MVC controls. One of the pages uses a Kendo grid which is bound to the view model. When I edit a row, there is a field which uses a dropdownlist control, and when the selection is changed, the remaining fields in the row should be updated to reflect that newly selected item..I am doing this with a JSON call which then returns the new view model to use for that row. However, I cannot figure out how to tell the grid to use the data that was returned from that JSON call. Any ideas?

EDIT:

I have attached some code. The issue now is that I can get the grid's datasource to 'refresh', but in the UpdateGridSource jscript function, at the grid.dataSource.read() line, the grid is now out of edit mode, and if I go to edit the row, the data is reverted back to how it originally was

(VIEW)

```
    @(Html.Kendo().Grid<RedFile.Models.QuickQuoteItemView>()
      .Name("QuoteItems")
      .Columns(c =>
      {
        c.Bound(p => p.Id).Hidden();
        c.Bound(p => p.Description).EditorTemplateName("Combobox");
        c.Bound(p => p.ItemQty);
        c.Bound(p => p.ItemPrice).Format("{0:c}");
        c.Bound(p => p.Total).ClientTemplate("#= kendo.format('{0:c}', Total)   #").FooterHtmlAttributes(new { style = "text-align:right;" }).ClientFooterTemplate("#= kendo.format('{0:c}', sum)#").HtmlAttributes(new { style = "text-align:right;" }).Width(100);
        c.Command(cmd => { cmd.Edit(); cmd.Destroy(); }).Title("Commands").Width(200);
      })
      .ToolBar(tb => tb.Create())
      .ClientDetailTemplateId("subitems")
      .Editable(eb => eb.Mode(GridEditMode.InLine).CreateAt(GridInsertRowPosition.Bottom))
      .Events(e=>e.Edit("editGrid"))
      .Scrollable()
      .DataSource(ds => ds
        .Ajax()
        .ServerOperation(false)
        .Aggregates(a =>
        {
            a.Add(p => p.LineTotal).Sum();
            a.Add(p => p.Total).Sum();

        })
       .Model(model =>
       {
            model.Id(p => p.Id);
            model.Field(p => p.LineTotal).Editable(false);
            model.Field(p => p.ItemPrice).Editable(true);
       })
      .Read(read => read.Action("GridSelect", "QuickQuote", new { qqid = Model.Id })).ServerOperation(false)
      .Create(create => create.Action("GridCreate", "QuickQuote", new { qqid = Model.Id }))
      .Update(update => update.Action("GridUpdate", "QuickQuote"))
      .Destroy(destroy => destroy.Action("GridDelete", "QuickQuote"))
      )
    )

    <script type="text/javascript">

    function dropDownSelectionChanged(e) {
      var dataItem = this.dataItem(e.item.index());
      UpdateGridSource(dataItem.Value);
    }

    function UpdateGridSource(DropDownValue) {
      var grid = $("#theGrid").data("kendoGrid");
      grid.dataSource.transport.options.read.url = '/Controller/refreshGridDataSource?selection=' + DropDownValue;
      grid.dataSource.read();
    }

    </script>
```

(CONTROLLER)

```
    public JsonResult refreshQuickQuoteTest2([DataSourceRequest] DataSourceRequest request, string selection)
    {
        QuickQuoteItem qqi = db.QuickQuoteItems.FirstOrDefault(p => p.ItemID == selection);

        QuickQuote quickQuoteOriginal = qqi.QuickQuote;

        QuickQuoteItemView qqiv = new QuickQuoteItemView();
        IEnumerable<QuickQuoteItemView> return2;

        qqiv.Id = qqi.Id;
        qqiv.ItemID = qqi.ItemID;
        qqiv.ItemPrice = qqi.ItemPrice;

        if (Session["quickQuote"] != null)
        {
            QuickQuote qq = (QuickQuote)(Session["quickQuote"]);

            if (Session["editingQuickQuoteId"] != null)
            {
                int row = Convert.ToInt32(Session["editingQuickQuoteId"]);
                foreach (var item in qq.QuickQuoteItems)
                {
                    if (item.Id == row)
                    {
                        QuickQuoteItem test = new QuickQuoteItem();
                        StandardItem stdItem = new StandardItem();
                        stdItem = db.StandardItems.Find(selection);
                        item.ItemPrice = stdItem.Price;
                        item.Description = stdItem.Description;
                        item.ItemID = stdItem.ItemId;
                    }
                }
            }                

            return2 = QuickQuoteItemViewItems(qq);
        }
        else
        {
            return2 = QuickQuoteItemViewItems(quickQuoteOriginal);
        }

        return Json(return2.ToDataSourceResult(request), JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use the grids Ajax binding to call your controller Update Action method

```
.DataSource(dataSource => dataSource
.Ajax()
.ServerOperation(false)
.Model(model => model.Id(p => p.SampleId))
.Update(read => read.Action("SampleGrid_Update", "Controller")))
```

Then you need to decorate your methods datasource parameter with the `DataSourceRequest` attribute and return the ModelState as a `DataSourceResult`

```
 [HttpPost]
    public ActionResult SampleGrid_Update([DataSourceRequest] DataSourceRequest dsRequest, IEnumerable<SampleViewModel> viewModel)
    {
        if (viewModel != null && ModelState.IsValid)
        {
            // other code goes here...
        }

        return Json(ModelState.ToDataSourceResult());
    }
```

You can view the samples and documentation on the Kendo [website](http://demos.kendoui.com/web/grid/editing-inline.html)

**Edit**

You can bind your ajax call to the change event of your dropdownlist and when this returns you can refresh the grid data from the server using

```
$("#gridId").data("kendoGrid").dataSource.read();
```

Comment: The issue here is that this does not occur on the update action method. The row essentially needs to be refreshed when the dropdown selection change event occurs, not when the row is updated. On the Kendo website grid example, just picture the 'ProductName' column using a dropdown instead of a textbox, which is bound to some products. When the product is changed, the 'Unit Price' and 'Units In Stock' columns need to reflect that newly selected product (change according to what is selected in the product dropdown)..does that clarify things?

Comment: Have edited my answer to include how to refresh the grid datasource. Could you post some of your code so that we can better understand the issue?

Comment: Thanks Longball, I have added some code. I am refreshing the grid datasource, but when .dataSource.read() is called, the grid is taken out of edit mode, which it should not be doing when a column value is changed. If this is the only way to refresh the row, I will need a workaround to put the row back in 'edit' mode after the dataSource is read in this case.

Comment: I found a way to get this working using the popup edit mode. Using the popup edit, I can change the fields being edited to the data returned from my ajax call, without having to do a grid.dataSource.read call. Thanks for your effort taking a look into this longball.